# unresolved reference warning - ON statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

When added a constraint in SQL, I am receiving an unresolved reference warning on the 'ON FG_LOGGING' line. Does it need to be declared as I'm not sure on this. This is an existing code I'm looking at that someone else built and cannot see when I search the file, any other mention of FG_LOGGING.

```
CREATE table Holidays.J2H.PriceCheckWorkList
(
PriceCheckWorkListId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
HotelID int,
HotelRoomID int,
PerPersonCost money,
CONSTRAINT [PK_PriceCheckWorkListId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PriceCheckWorkListId)
) ON FG_LOGGING
```

Comment: [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)`ON { <partition_scheme> | filegroup | "default" } Specifies the partition scheme or filegroup on which the table is stored. If <partition_scheme> is specified, the table is to be a partitioned table whose partitions are stored on a set of one or more filegroups specified in <partition_scheme>.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are likely getting is:

> Invalid filegroup 'FG_LOGGING' specified.

What the error effectively means is that the script was originally intended for a server which had [FILEGROUPS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189314(v=sql.105).aspx) set up to store tables in specific drives and folders on the server. Seemingly, the database on which you are now trying to create doesn't have these File Groups - apparantly the full database creation script hasn't been run.

You can either change the file group to run on the default file group (or remove it entirely), e.g.

```
CREATE table Holidays.J2H.PriceCheckWorkList
(
PriceCheckWorkListId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
HotelID int,
HotelRoomID int,
PerPersonCost money,
CONSTRAINT [PK_PriceCheckWorkListId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PriceCheckWorkListId)
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Alternatively, you (or your DBA) can recreate the filegroup and associated files on your server (replace the folder with an appropriate path for your server):

```
ALTER DATABASE Holidays
ADD FILEGROUP FG_Logging;

ALTER DATABASE Holidays
ADD FILE 
(
NAME = FG_Logging,
FILENAME = 'c:\temp\FG_Logging.ndf')
TO FILEGROUP FG_Logging;
```